# Why can a log backup not be taken without first taking a full backup?

Tags: sql-server, backup, transaction-log

I've created a *new database* using the FULL recovery model. Now I am trying to take a log backup without first taking a full backup.

I'm aware that SQL Server won't allow us to do so, but I want to know *why* SQL Server is preventing it?

Below is the script I've used for testing purposes:

```
CREATE DATABASE TESTING
GO
BACKUP LOG TESTING TO DISK='G:\TESTING_LOG.TRN'
```

Answer (score 7):

When a database is switched to `FULL` recovery, it behaves as if it was in `SIMPLE` recovery until you take a full database backup. Up to that moment, you cannot take log backups, because the log gets truncated on `CHECKPOINT`, as happens in `SIMPLE` recovery.

See [this article by Paul Randal](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/new-script-is-that-database-really-in-the-full-recovery-mode/) for reference.

Log backups form part of a chain that allow the *whole database* to be recovered. The chain *starts* with a full backup (complete copy), and may continue from that point with further differential or log backups.

[image: Recovery example]

<sub>Image taken from [Complete Database Restores (Full Recovery Model)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-nz/library/ms187495.aspx)</sub>

A transaction log backup contains the information needed to:

- Redo all committed changes to the database since the last full or log backup
- Undo in-progress (not yet committed) changes at the time the log backup was taken

In *principle*, it would be possible to recreate a database from log information alone, if every log backup ever was available, *including* the initial creation of the database itself, but that is not the way it was implemented.

As it is, a full backup is necessary is start the recovery path.